# Changing the individual pixels of a Gtk.Image

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I am trying to set individual pixels on a Gtk.Image widget. The documentation states that the ImageProp property of a Gtk.Image returns a Gdk.Image which seems to let you edit the individual pixels, but whenever I use this it only returns null.

My solution so far is to load the image from disk as a System.Drawing.Bitmap, edit it, save it to a temporary file, then load it back into a Gtk.Image, but this is obviously not ideal.

For

```
Gtk.Image image = new Gtk.Image("images/test.png");
Gdk.Image gdkImage = image.ImageProp;
```

Why is gdkImage always null?

The image itself loads and displays correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Although I have no prior experience with GTK# or C#, based on whatever little I know about Gtk & what I could look up online, I will make an attempt to provide some inputs.
You can get `Gdk.Image` for a `Gtk.Image` only if you have created the `Gtk.Image` from a `Gdk.Image` using the mentioned property, otherwise you will get `null` as in your case where you are creating it from a file or as suggested by creating it from `Gdk.Pixbuf`. In current case, you could try to get `Gdk.Image` from `Gdk.Drawable` using `Gdk.Drawable.GetImage` method or use `Gdk.Image.Get` method. You can make use of `GdkWindow` associated with `Gtk.Image` as `Gdk.Drawable` in the mentioned cases. For `Gdk.Window` to be valid the widget should have been shown or realized. But it is quite likely that you may end with `null` in both the cases.
Side Note: [`GdkImage` APIs are deprecated in the newer versions of Gtk](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Images.html), please note it *may* not be so in the case of GTK# as yet.
Thus it might be a good idea to use `Gdk.Pixbuf` instead. It is possible to get pixels for `GdkPixbuf` and modify the same in GTK. But unfortunately it appears that in case of GTK# [that particular property (Pixels)](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aGdk.Pixbuf) of `Gdk.Pixbuf` is made as read only. One option maybe to use [`Gdk.Pixdata`](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aGdk.Pixdata) from `Gdk.Pixbuf` which is created from the image, modify the pixels using methods in `Gdk.Pixdata`, create a `Gdk.Pixbuf` out of it & copy that back to the original `Gdk.Pixbuf`. Unfortunately I cannot be sure about this, you can give it a shot though.
Alternatively you can consider drawing onto `Gdk.Drawable`. There are examples available wherein the `Gdk.Drawable` assocaited with `Gtk.Widget` (usually `Gtk.DrawingArea`) is updated in the `Expose Event` callback.
I hope that the information provided can provide you with some pointer to proceed.

Comment: At this point im feeling like this is more trouble than its worth. To anyone in the future looking at this, I'd recommend starting with drawing onto a Gdk.Drawable, as all the other suggestions seem to be impossible to use (Gdk.Drawable needs a Gdk.Drawable to create itself, pixbuf.RenderToDrawable requires a Drawable and a Gdk.GC (whatever that is) and so on. A bunch of these object only have constructors which take IntPtrs, which doesn't seem very helpful. Not only that, but GtkSharp has no documentation in its DLLs)

Thanks for the effort though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pixbuf` first:

```
Gdk.Pixbuf pixbufImage = new Gdk.Pixbuf(@"images/test.png");
Gtk.Image gtkImage = new Gtk.Image(pixbufImage);
Gdk.Image gdkImage = gtkImage.ImageProp;
```